# Java compile error for a switch statement

Tags: java, compilation

I have written this

```
public static void setIsolationLevel(Isolev level) {
    try{
        switch(level){
            case READ_UNCOMMITTED;
            conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
            break;
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't compile. It says it is missing a `:`. What is the problem? I have tried to put ":" every where.

Comment: case READ_UNCOMMITTED:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have

```
case READ_UNCOMMITTED;
```

with a semicolon. You need a colon

```
case READ_UNCOMMITTED:
```

Comment: Thank you :) i have must have looked at it too much since i couldn't see that :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure the compiler is also giving you a line number:

```
public static void setIsolationLevel(Isolev level) {
    try{
        switch(level){
        case READ_UNCOMMITTED: // <-------- here, replace ; with :
           conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
           break;
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement in Java goes like:

```
switch(thingy){
    case CASE1: 
       ...
    break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `case READ_UNCOMMITTED;` needs to be changed to `case READ_UNCOMMITTED:`.  Note the colon instead of the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just only one clause within switch you don't need a switch - You can simply use a 'if' statement which will make the code cleaner.

```
public static void setIsolationLevel(Isolev level) {
    try{
        if(READ_UNCOMMITTED.equals(level)){
            conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
        }
    }catch (SQLException e){
        throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```